# Appendices appears in PDF file as part of previous chapter

Tags: pdf, appendices, parts

I have a LaTeX report structured as follows:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\part{Part 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\part{Part 4}
\chapter{Chapter 5}

\appendixpage 
\appendix    
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Appendix 1 }
\chapter{Appendix 2}

\end{document}
```

But when this LaTex is compiled to a PDF file, the Appendices are displayed as part of the Part 4, but not as a distinct element of the document itself, i.e.:

[image]

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: According to your MWE the problem is that file added with `\input` since you add it before the `Appendix 1` that use a chapter. If in the external file `Appendices` you use `\chapter` probably your problem  will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that "Appendix 1" and "Appendix 2" should appear under "Appendices".
Package `bookmark` helps to raise the level of "Appendices" to a `\part`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\part{Part 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\part{Part 4}
\chapter{Chapter 5}

\appendix
\bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Appendix 1 }
\chapter{Appendix 2}

\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- `\input{Appendices}` ignored because of missing `Appendices.tex`.
- `abstract` is an environment in class `report`.

Comment: Thanks. That appears to have worked. And I've corrected my original LaTeX.